# how to display binary result written in a file with c language

Tags: c, binaryfiles

I need to write the value of the address of a struct in file with C language.

```
void func_1 ( struct_1 *st)
```

And the type struct_1 located at a file.h

```
struct struct_1 {
      target_ulong a;   
      target_ulong b; 
      uint32_t c; 
      uint16_t size;
}
```

I write in the file file.txt with this code

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("/path/to//doc.txt", "wb");
int x=sizeof((void *)st);
fwrite (st, x, 100, fp);
fclose(fp);
```

And the result is like that when I open the doc.txt

[image]

It seems that the format of the file can't be open with gedit. can you propose another tools to open it.

Comment: Address point to memory locations. They do not point to locations in a file.

Comment: What value are you expecting to be in `x`? If you want the size of the struct you want to use `sizeof(*st)`.

Comment: As @Chris write, `sizeof((void *)x)` will return the size of a void pointer.

Comment: I hate to point to advance Linux C in what looks like a novice post, but this is possible. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html

Comment: i try it and the file becomes empty

Comment: @gerrard2461 empty as in zero length?

Comment: @Chris Turner yes exactly

Comment: Wait - are you trying to write the *address* of `st` or the *contents* of `st` to your file?  If the former (which will be meaningless when you try to read from the file later), you would use `fwrite( &st, sizeof st, 1, fp);`.  If the latter, you would use `fwrite( st, sizeof *st, 1, fp );`.

Comment: i'm trying to write the address  , i tried but always the file is empty that can have a consequence of the asci editor ? because the file is opened to write binary no ?

Comment: An address is not 100 bytes long — you are writing far too much.  Since you don't show the definition of `st`, we're all guessing about what you're doing.  Please show an MCVE ([MCVE]) — which will only be an extra 5 lines or less of code — so we can answer more sensibly.

Comment: @gerrard2461: So you're writing *binary* data to a file, but trying to view it as *text*?  If so, then yeah, that's a problem.  You'd need to view the file with a hex (binary) editor.  If you want to write the *text representation* of the address value to the file, you'd use `fprintf( fp, "%p", (void *) st );`

Comment: the code is too complicated so im trying to show it easy

Comment: @gerrard2461: it's still not clear to me why you want to write the *address* of the struct to the file; are you writing for a system that allows you access to physical memory addresses?

Comment: @john Bode in fact im trying to have a trace for output in order to understand how i will implemant the trace of functions (the code is so complicated

Comment: @ John Bode i have this error when i  tried fprintf( fp, "%p", (void *) st );        error: passing argument 1 of ‘fprintf’ from incompatible pointer type [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
 fprintf( st, "%p", (void *) st );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the editor who by default search the ASCII code and display character in this case i open the file in order to write in binary mode so that's why the problem occurs

i used A HEXADECIMAL editor that can open and display binary file